# Proper way to allow access to systems within different offices?

Tags: firewalls

I have a system that sysadmins in a few of our global offices need to access.  What is the best way to grant them access through our firewall to this system?  I don't think that having them use static IPs and then using the firewall to allow those specific IPs access is a scalable or great solution.

Some more information:

We have a firewall that groups many of our systems into separate VLANs. Our disparate offices connect either through VPN, or through an MPLS connection.

So for example, someone in Italy needs to access a web application hosted in the US. This would require the network team to tweak the ACLs to ensure that the individual there can access the system.

Comment: You have not given us enough information. We'll have to assume your entire structure in order to give an answer.

Comment: After your edit, things still aren't clear. If they have VPN access, why is the firewall still an issue? Authenticate the user, not the IP.

Comment: That to me is the correct approach. Unfortunately the approach they seem to have taken was to restrict who can access specific VLANs. The server that these individuals need access to is on a VLAN that only allows a few systems to connect to it.

Comment: Ok - then your scenario is far simpler than you laid out. Unfortunately, it's simple VLAN pain that you either need to re-architect to permit the reality that remote users need access, or to pivot users once they have VLAN access.

Answer (score 3):

Separate physical locations can share the same logical network using a VPN.  A client's IP address can be used in a [multi-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) system, but a password and a Key FOB is more commonly used.

Answer (score -2):

IP Addresses are trivial for an attacker to spoof and should not be considered anything other than a log analysis data point.

You should also know that MPLS 'VPNs' are not as secure as a real VPN.  Paul Coggin expounded on this at BSides Nashville: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/bsidesnashville2014/300-bending-and-twisting-networks-paul-coggin.

@schroeder is correct - authenticate the user, strongly.  Here's (reg-free) pdf on how to setup a network with 2FA and have all the authorization done in AD using the MS radius plugin NPS: http://www.wikidsystems.com/webdemo/Two-factor_Authentication_in_your_Network_eGuide.pdf.

Comment: "Trivial" to spoof IPs while actively connected? Can you provide evidence of this?

Comment: The other problem the OP has is that there is no direct connection to the target from the remote user. It's not an authentication problem, but a logical access one.